# How do you recieve your current php file url

Tags: php, url, navigation, uri

I want to make navigation easier, so lets say when i have page called

```
http://test.nl/admin/xxx.php?id=423
```

if i want to redirect to the same page with a different parameter. i can do

```
Header("Location: xxx.php$rest");
```

but is there a way to get the xxx.php dynamic?
i tried $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] and it worked on localhost but not on my server.
I get: http://test.nl/test.nl/admin/xxx.php?id=423

Comment: `$_SERVER` depends on the server environment. You need to search the site a bit there are some good suggestions around, as you can imagine you're not the first one having a problem with it. Also look what is commonly available: http://php.net/reserved.variables.server - see as well the user-notes on the manual page.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`$basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

This should give you the name of the file in the URL including the extension.  Of course, if you wanted to have the name of the file **without** the file extension then try:

`$basename = str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Answer (score 1):

You should use URL rewriting. Take a look at the component `Zend_Router` in the Zend framework.

And for the purposes of getting the current file URL:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
          $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
          $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
}

echo curPageURL();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to `/xxx.php?$rest`. You don't need the full address if you aren't leaving the directory.

Comment: i know but i am looking for a way to extract the "xxx.php" not the full url

Comment: To get just the file name you can use `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what it wouldn't work on a production site, but does locally.

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?$rest");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable  to retrieve the current script's path i.e fullpath and filename of current file

For more details about $_SERVER variable please refer the documentation mentioned in below url

https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server

Answer (score 0):

You not need current url, you can link new query string:

with html link:

```
<a href="?foo=bar">
```

or php redirection:

```
Header("Location: ?foo=bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using regex for these cases. (Or rather cases where none of the other answers apply, like accessing a file relative to this one.)

`$foldername = preg_replace('/(.*)(\/admin\/.*)/', '$2', dirname(__FILE__));`

`$filename = preg_replace('/(.*)(\/admin\/.*)/', '$2', __FILE__);`

Note that `\/admin\/` is at the start of the second capturing group. `$2` gives preg replace a direct reference to the entire capturing group. Therefore admin has to be the first folder from the web root in which the capturing group resides.